# How to get an H1 text inside a div through an omouseover event and innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, onmouseover

I'm trying to write the content of my H1 inside a div when I put the mouse over the H1, but only get [Object HTMLHeadingElement], not the text itself. I'm a total beginner and I'm trying it with the innerHTML property. Thank you all!

```
HTML code:

<h1 id="phrase" onmouseover="writeInDiv2()">Hi all</h1>

JavaScript code:

var text = document.getElementById("phrase");

function writeInDiv2(){
    if(div2.style.display != "none"){
        div2.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options to get the text-content:

```
// Webkit, Mozilla, Opera (and other standards-compliant) browsers
var text = document.getElementById("phrase").textContent;

// Microsoft Internet Explorer (though this might have changed in IE 10)
var text = document.getElementById("phrase").innerText;

// Possibly works, though assumes the h1 contains only a text-node
var text = document.getElementById("phrase").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

For efficiency, with the following HTML:

```
<h1 onmouseover="writeInDiv2(this, 'div2')">Hi all</h1>
<h1 onmouseover="writeInDiv2(this, 'div2')">Another message</h1>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

I'd suggest:

```
function writeInDiv2(el, textInto){
    var div2 = textInto.nodeType === 1 ? textInto : document.getElementById(textInto),
        text = el.textContent ? el.textContent : el.innerText;
    while (div2.firstChild){
        div2.removeChild(div2.firstChild);
    }
    div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PDmwn/).

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I have to look calmly your solution because I'm a beginner but I've seen in JS Fiddle that it works perfectly. I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `div2.innerHTML = text.innerHTML;`